# Definition of crossed homomorphisms

Tags: group-cohomology

According to Silverman(Arithmetic of Elliptic curves):

> The definition of a crossed
>   homomorphisms, is a map $f : G \to M$ satisfying
>   $f(ab)=bf(a)+f(b)$ for all $a$, $b$ in G.

According to many other books:

> The definition of a crossed
>   homomorphisms, is a map $f : G \to M$ satisfying
>   $f(ab)=f(a)+af(b)$ for all $a$, $b$ in G.

Whether both the definitions are the same or different?
If both the definitions are same then how I can define an action of $G/N$ on the first cohomology group
$H^1(N,A)$.(where $N\trianglelefteq G$)

Comment: See (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031287/induced-action-of-quotient-group-on-the-subgroup-cohomology)

Comment: why $ (g\cdot f)$ is a crossed homomorphism w.r.t that action? @ParthivBasu

Comment: There is no trick to it, you just have to do an explicit computation to prove that $ (g \cdot f)(ab) = (g \cdot f)(a) + a (g \cdot f) (b) $.

Comment: $(g\cdot f)(ab)=gf(g^{-1}abg)=gf(g^{-1}agg^{-1}bg)=gf(g^{-1}ag)+g^{-1}ag^{2}f(g^{-1}bg)$. After that how can i proceed.@ParthivBasu

Comment: I think the difference is in whether $M$ is a left- or right $G$-module. In Silverman, $M$ is a right $G$-module. You've changed the notation from what's in Silverman (if you were looking at Appendix B, as I am): I think it should really be  $f(ab) = f(a) b + f(b)$. In many other sources on group cohomology, $M$ is instead a *left* $G$-module, so the second definition is correct. In Galois cohomology the Galois group naturally acts on the right which is why Silverman considers right modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Claim:** $\left( g\cdot f\right) \left( h_{1}h_{2}\right) =h_{1}\left( g\cdot f\right) \left( h_{2}\right) +\left( g\cdot f\right) \left( h_{1}\right) $ for all $h_1 , h_2 \in H$.

*Proof.*  From the other answer you have

$$(g\cdot f)(h)=gf\left(g^{-1}(hg)\right)
=gf(g^{-1})+f(hg)=gf(g^{-1})+f(h)+hf(g).$$

Using this equality we get

$$ \begin{align} \ h_{1}\left( g \cdot f\right) \left( h_{2}\right) &=h_{1}[gf\left( g^{-1}\right) +f\left( h_{2}\right) +h_{2}f\left( g\right) ] \\ &= h_{1}gf\left( g^{-1}\right) +h_{1}f\left( h_{2}\right) + h_{1}h_{2}f\left( g\right), \\ \left( g\cdot f\right) \left( h_{1}\right) & =gf\left( g^{-1}\right) +f\left( h_{1}\right) +h_{1}f\left( g\right) \end{align}$$
and 
$$ \begin{align} \left( g \cdot f\right) \left( h_{1}h_{2}\right) &=gf\left( g^{-1}\right) +f\left( h_{1}h_{2}\right) +h_{1}h_{2}f\left( g\right) \\ &= gf\left( g^{-1}\right) +h_{1}f\left( h_{2}\right) +f\left( h_{1}\right)  +h_{1}h_{2}f\left( g\right). \end{align} $$

Note that $h_{1}[ f\left( g\right) +gf\left( g^{-1}\right)] = 0$, so the LHS is indeed equal to the RHS.

Comment: I hope this is right. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: yes, Thanks a lot.